# Engineering font recommendation

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

Might anyone have the name/source of a good engineering font for symbols -- like diameter (circle with angled line), depth (en-dash sort of line with downward arrow), and counterbalance (like a sideways bracket)?

The client's engineers suggested a font called "AIGDT." It's eluding me. I found a free site that had an engineering font that looked good, but it came with malware, and I cancelled the install. I wouldn't mind buying the font, as long as it's from a legitimate source. I'm on Mac OS X.

Comment: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/industry-engineering/

Answer (score 3):

Get [osifont](https://github.com/hikikomori82/osifont) it is designed for this use case and is GPL If its missing something your more than welcome to add it. whats better then this it implements a very big set of language support and follows ISO standard font guidelines.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used to work in a technical publishing and for all those elements we used the [Mathematical Pi Family](https://www.linotype.com/1563/universal-mathematical-pi-family.html) via Linotype.com

The [Universal Mathematical PI](https://www.linotype.com/57815/universal-mathematical-pi-product.html) come with 690 technical characters:

[image: math pi]